# What is the difference between p.WaitForExit() and p.WaitForExit(Integer.MaxValue) in this specific case?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, process

Basically I'm launching asynchronously a `Process` and I'm waiting for that `Process` to exit using a `Task`, I don't have any problems with my code below, but I've found a little issue that I would like to understand...

The issue is that if I use the method `process.WaitForExit()` and I try to cancel the `Task` (or what is the same, kill the process) then the process never exits so the sub-thread will hangs forever, instead that if I use the method `process.WaitForExit(Integer.MaxValue)` all works perfectlly.

Why happens that?, what is the difference that makes the process unable to recognize the process has exited?.

The `Process` instance:

```
''' <summary>
''' The CMD <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process"/> instance.
''' </summary>
Private WithEvents cmdProcess As New Process With
   {
       .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
       .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With
                        {
                           .FileName = "cmd.exe",
                           .Arguments = String.Empty,
                           .RedirectStandardInput = False,
                           .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
                           .RedirectStandardError = True,
                           .UseShellExecute = False,
                           .CreateNoWindow = True
                        }
   }
```

The `Task`  Initializer:

```
Private Sub StartTask()

   Me.cmdTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
   Me.cmdTaskCTS = New Threading.CancellationTokenSource
   Me.cmdTaskCT = cmdTaskCTS.Token

End Sub
```

The job that the `Task` does:

```
Private Sub CMDAutomate()

   With Me.cmdProcess

       .StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/C ""{0}""", Me.PingArguments)
       .Start()
       .BeginOutputReadLine()
       .BeginErrorReadLine()
       .WaitForExit(Integer.MaxValue)

   End With

End Sub
```

And the `Task` canceller:

```
Private Sub CancelTask()

   If Not Me.cmdProcess.HasExited Then

       With Me.cmdProcess
           .CancelOutputRead()
           .CancelErrorRead()
           .Kill() ' kill process (cmd.exe)
       End With

       ' cancel the task.
       Me.cmdTaskCTS.Cancel()
       ' wait for the task cancellation finishes.
       Me.cmdTask.Wait()

   End If

End Sub
```

---

This is the entire code if needed:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class Form1

   Private cmdTask As Task
   Private cmdTaskCTS As New CancellationTokenSource
   Private cmdTaskCT As CancellationToken

   ''' <summary>
   ''' The CMD <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process"/> instance.
   ''' </summary>
   Private WithEvents cmdProcess As New Process With
       {
           .EnableRaisingEvents = True,
           .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With
                            {
                               .FileName = "cmd.exe",
                               .Arguments = String.Empty,
                               .RedirectStandardInput = False,
                               .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
                               .RedirectStandardError = True,
                               .UseShellExecute = False,
                               .CreateNoWindow = True
                            }
       }

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Gets the ping commandline arguments.
   ''' </summary>
   Private ReadOnly Property PingArguments As String
       Get
           Return String.Format("ping.exe -t ""{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}""",
                               TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text,
                               TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text)
       End Get
   End Property

   Private Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
   Handles btnsend.Click

       Me.StartTask()

   End Sub

   Private Sub CMDAutomate()

       With Me.cmdProcess

           .StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/C ""{0}""", Me.PingArguments)
           .Start()
           .BeginOutputReadLine()
           .BeginErrorReadLine()
           .WaitForExit(Integer.MaxValue)

       End With

   End Sub

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Occurs when an application writes to its redirected <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardOutput"/> stream.
   ''' Occurs when an application writes to its redirected <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardError"/>  stream.
   ''' </summary>
   Private Sub cmdProcess_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs) _
   Handles cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived,
           cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived

       Select Case txtresults.InvokeRequired

           Case True
               txtresults.Invoke(Sub() txtresults.AppendText("" & e.Data))
               txtresults.Invoke(Sub() txtresults.AppendText(Environment.NewLine))

           Case Else
               txtresults.AppendText(e.Data)
               txtresults.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)

       End Select

#If DEBUG Then
       ' Debug.WriteLine(e.Data)
#End If

   End Sub

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Occurs when a <see cref="System.Diagnostics.Process"/> exits.
   ''' </summary>
   Private Sub cmdProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
   Handles cmdProcess.Exited

       Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("cmdProcess has exited with exit code: {0}",
                                     DirectCast(sender, Process).ExitCode))

   End Sub

   Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) _
   Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked

       ' limpio el texto de cada textbox.
       For Each tb As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
           tb.Clear()
       Next tb

       ' cancelo la tarea en segundo plano.
       Me.CancelTask()

   End Sub

   Private Sub StartTask()

       Me.cmdTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
       Me.cmdTaskCTS = New Threading.CancellationTokenSource
       Me.cmdTaskCT = cmdTaskCTS.Token

   End Sub

   Private Sub CancelTask()

       ' Si el proceso no se ha detenido...
       If Not Me.cmdProcess.HasExited Then

           With Me.cmdProcess
               ' cancelo la lectura de los outputs.
               .CancelOutputRead()
               .CancelErrorRead()
               .Kill() ' mato el proceso (cmd.exe)
           End With

           ' Cancelo la tarea en segundo plano.
           Me.cmdTaskCTS.Cancel()
           ' Espero a que la tarea se haya cancelado.
           Me.cmdTask.Wait()

       End If

   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: try set the Process.SynchronizingObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell just by reading this, and with my limited experience with asynchronous tasks, it may have to do with the fact that .WaitForExit is called within the Task, just after the Start.
This is what the MSDN page on Process.Kill has to say about using Kill and WaitForExit:
"The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited."

In this case WaitForExit is being called before the Kill, which is only called if the task is cancelled.  So only WaitForExit(Int32) is working because that will wait only for that certain amount of time, instead of indefinitely (as it is going to here).

See MSDN pages about WaitForExit:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx,

and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1.

I hope that helps, anyway.